# How the bluetooth connection that is made via service persist across all the other activity in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, bluetooth-lowenergy

Consider there is `1 service` and `2 Activity.`

`Activity 1` is for connecting to the bluetooth device.

`Activity 2` is for getting the data from the BLE Device

I have implemented both the connection and data read part Using Service because there is a need to collect data from BLE device even when the app is in background mode.

So how  can I use the service to make connection during the Activity 1 and use the same service from Activity 2 for collecting the data with the same connection.

Comment: You can either bind to the `Service` in both activities, or you can call `startService()` in both activites to send requests to the `Service`. What have you tried and what is the problem? In general, this architecture works fine.

Comment: Problem is as soon as when I unbind the service from the activity 1 the GATT connection is disconnected. So there is a need to connect the gatt again in activity 2 in the service connection callback as soon as activity 2 is binded to the service

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that your `Service` runs until you explicitly shut it down. Return `START_STICKY` from `onStartCommand()` and your `Service` will stay running even if the client `Activity` unbinds. Make sure that you have some way to shut the `Service` down (using `stopService()` or `stopSelf()` when you are done with it.

Comment: Thank you.. Basically do we need to get the same instance across all the acctivity right?

Comment: Yes. But services are singletons. Once you start a service, as long as it stays running you can communicate with it (and it is the only instance). Android won't start another instance of a service if there is already one running. It just routes the `Intent` to that instance.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked on a bluetooth service.But I guess you can create a bluetooth stream object in the first activity which can be shared with the second activity.Use the stream object in the second activity to do communications.